# Prometheus / Kubernetes showing InstanceDown / PrometheusTargetMissing

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, prometheus-operator

We've got multiple k8s cluster on which we installed prometheues operator.
One particular cluster shows targetmissing/instance down for whatever reason

How were they setup? Kubespray
How many nodes? 9 wrk / 3 inf / 3 mst
k8s version? 1.15.9
How did you install your Prometheus? helm (2) chart > stable/prometheus-operator

[Prometheus TargetMissing / InstanceDown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/itvyh.png)

But when I check the actual endpoints, it all looks fine.

```html
root@k8s-prd-mst01 :~> k -n kube-system describe ep prometheus-prometheus-oper-kubelet                                                                                                       
Name:         prometheus-prometheus-oper-kubelet
Namespace:    kube-system
Labels:       k8s-app=kubelet
Annotations:  <none>
Subsets:
  Addresses:          IPs-REDACTED
  NotReadyAddresses:  <none>
  Ports:
    Name           Port   Protocol
    ----           ----   --------
    http-metrics   10255  TCP
    cadvisor       4194   TCP
    https-metrics  10250  TCP

Events:  <none>
```

I've re-installed prometheues about 3 times without luck and can't reproduce this error on any other cluster. I wonder how I can troubleshoot this any deeper. I guess something I can check in the pods but I'm not sure what?

I have about 3 other clusters dev / sandbox and prod cluster in another DC that don't have these alerts which have been installed the same way, so trying to get to the bottom of the problem. Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: Could you share more details regarding your cluster? How was it setup? How many nodes? Which k8s version? How did you install your Prometheus?

Comment: Hey Wiktor,

How was it setup? Kubespray
How many nodes? 9 wrk / 3 inf / 3 mst
Which k8s version? 1.15.9
How did you install your Prometheus? helm (2) chart > stable/prometheus-operator

Anything else you'd like to know more specifically?
As I said previously I have about 3 other dev / sandbox and prod cluster that don't have these alerts which have been installed the same way, so trying to get to the bottom of the problem.

Thank you!

Comment: Could you please edit your question with the info provided?

Answer (score 0):

I see one issue and one recommendation here.

**Issue:**

> How did you install your Prometheus? helm (2) chart >
> stable/prometheus-operator

The problem is that this chart is [deprecated](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/prometheus-operator#%EF%B8%8F--deprecated):

> Further development has moved to
> [prometheus-community/helm-charts](https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts). The chart has been renamed
> [kube-prometheus-stack](https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/kube-prometheus-stack) to more clearly reflect that it installs
> the `kube-prometheus` project stack, within which Prometheus Operator
> is only one component.

You should use the linked resources instead. Note that the [kube-prometheus-stack](https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/kube-prometheus-stack#kube-prometheus-stack) has some specific prerequisites:

- Kubernetes 1.16+
- Helm 3+

which brings us to the second point:

**Recommendation:**

> k8s version? 1.15.9
> helm (2)

This version of Kubernetes is quite old as the most recent one is v1.19. The same goes with the Helm version. I strongly suggest upgrading your cluster and trying to keep the versions up to date as much as possible to avoid using deprecated solutions.

Comment: Thank you Wiktor, I'm aware of these facts but I want to get to basis of this issue with the components I have. Not update the components. So it would be appreciated if someone could help point me into a direction of actually trying to solve the issue on hand.